# How to remove duplicate terms in a vocabulary

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary with many terms that are duplicates. How can I remove those terms?

I have many duplicates; I need a way to delete them that is not deleting them one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this code once in hook_init or custom php block or using drush

```
<?php

$vid = 1; // Replace 1 by vocabulary id for which you want to remove duplicates.

$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid, $parent = 0, $max_depth = NULL, $load_entities = FALSE);

// Loop through all terms in vocabulary
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  // Get all matching terms by term name
  $matching_terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term->name);
  foreach ($matching_terms as $matching_term) {
    /* Check matching term belongs to vocabulary we are searching and matching term should not be exact term that first found so that duplicate can be removed */
    if ($matching_term->vid == $vid && $matching_term->tid != $term->tid) {
      // Do Term Delete
      taxonomy_term_delete($matching_term->tid); 
    } 
  }
}

?>
```

**Important Note:** Take Database backup before running above code, so that you can restore if something goes wrong !

Comment: Its worth noting that this deletes terms without updating or checking references to other nodes. Its very dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

The [Term Merge](https://drupal.org/project/term_merge) module could help you.

> When using taxonomy for free tagging purposes, it's easy to end up with several terms having the same meaning. This may be due to spelling errors, or different users simply making up synonymous terms as they go.
>
> You, as an administrator, may then want to correct such errors or unify synonymous terms, thereby pruning the taxonomy to a more manageable set. This module allows you to merge multiple terms into one, while updating all fields referring to those terms to refer to the replacement term instead.

Comment: This is definitely the best option.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the Rules, To do this:

```
**Event**
After updating existing content
```

I chose after updating a content so you can chose all nodes and select update, which can be unpublish/publish - update url alias, any will work.

```
**Conditions**
Content is of type
```

and enter your content type

```
**Actions**
Add loop
```

Make sure the loop loops through your tags, my tags machine-name is "field-basic-tags" so you would chose something like "node:field-basic-tags" in the loop Data selector.

then you would add an action to that loop,

```
Add an item to a list
```

Chose "list-item:parent" from the data-selector

And check Enforce uniqueness box
and maybe you can also add,

```
Show a message on the site
```

to make sure your code worked.

here is an export of the rule.

```
    { "rules_enforce_uniqness_tag" : {
    "LABEL" : "Enforce Uniqness Tag",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "node_update" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : { "node" : [ "node" ], "type" : { "value" : { "page" : "page" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "node:field-basic-tags" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
          "DO" : [
            { "list_add" : {
                "list" : [ "list-item:parent" ],
                "item" : [ "list-item" ],
                "unique" : 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Done" } }
    ]
  }
}
```